# Error only on the real device. Works on all emulators

Tags: android

I am making an application where it is presented a list of online radios in a listView, this list is obtained thru a MySql database online. I tested my application in all versions of emulators and it worked well. But in the device, the application terminates. When I connect via usb does not close the application, but does not load Json content.

With the device connected via usb debugging does not charge the radios

The log:

```
03-01 17:35:05.109: E/Buffer Error(2273): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 17:35:05.109: E/JSON Parser(2273): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListaRadios extends ListActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaradios;
    private static String url_radios = "Url to php mysql connection with";
    private static final String TAG_SUCESSO = "sucesso";
    private static final String TAG_RADIOS = "radios";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";

    JSONArray radios = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_radios);

        listaradios = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new LoadAllRadios().execute();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id_item) {

                String id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);

                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void direciona(Class<?> menu){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, menu);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.contato:
                direciona(Contato.class);
                return true;
            case R.id.sugerir:
                direciona(Sugerir.class);
                return true;
          case R.id.listar:
                direciona(ListaRadios.class);
          return true;
            case R.id.player:
                direciona(Player.class);
          return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    class LoadAllRadios extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListaRadios.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Buscando rádios. Aguarde...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_radios, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Todas as rádios: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int sucesso = json.getInt(TAG_SUCESSO);

                if (sucesso == 1) {
                    radios = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RADIOS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < radios.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = radios.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NOME, nome);

                        listaradios.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListaRadios.this, 
                            listaradios, R.layout.lista_item_radios, 
                            new String[] {TAG_ID, TAG_NOME},
                            new int[] {R.id.id, R.id.nome});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
$resposta = array();
require_once 'db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radios") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    $resposta["radios"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $radio = array();
        $radio["id"] = $row["id"];
        $radio["nome"] = $row["nome"];
        $radio["site"] = $row["site"];
        $radio["imagem"] = $row["imagem"];
        $radio["url_streaming"] = $row["url_streaming"];
        array_push($resposta["radios"], $radio);
    }
    $resposta["sucesso"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($resposta);
} else {
    $resposta["sucesso"] = 0;
    $resposta["mensagem"] = "Não foram encontradas rádios.";
    echo json_encode($resposta);
}
?>
```

What can it be?

If I run the emulator the output of this is below:

```
03-01 18:41:40.047: D/Todas as rádios:(594): {"sucesso":1,"radios":[{"site":"www.radiomiriam.com.br","id":"1","url_streaming":"http:\/\/69.64.48.96:9880\/","nome":"Radio Miriam","imagem":""},{"site":"www.clarimdopampa.com.br","id":"2","url_streaming":"http:\/\/70.36.96.25:9928\/","nome":"Radio Clarim do Pampa","imagem":""},{"site":"","id":"5","url_streaming":"http:\/\/189.76.158.139:50004\/","nome":"Itapema FM - RS","imagem":""}]}
```

But if I run the usb debug output does not list this just this:

```
03-01 18:48:21.319: I/System.out(3717): Debugger has connected
03-01 18:48:21.319: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:21.519: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:21.719: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:21.919: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:22.119: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:22.319: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:22.519: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:22.719: I/System.out(3717): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-01 18:48:22.919: I/System.out(3717): debugger has settled (1475)
03-01 18:48:23.699: W/System.err(3717): java.net.UnknownHostException: nsi.inf.br
03-01 18:48:23.709: W/System.err(3717):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:508)
03-01 18:48:23.709: W/System.err(3717):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:296)
03-01 18:48:23.719: W/System.err(3717):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:258)
03-01 18:48:23.719: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
03-01 18:48:23.719: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-01 18:48:23.729: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-01 18:48:23.739: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
03-01 18:48:23.739: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at com.nsistations.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at com.nsistations.ListaRadios$LoadAllRadios.doInBackground(ListaRadios.java:120)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at com.nsistations.ListaRadios$LoadAllRadios.doInBackground(ListaRadios.java:1)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-01 18:48:23.749: W/System.err(3717):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-01 18:48:23.759: W/System.err(3717):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-01 18:48:23.759: W/System.err(3717):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-01 18:48:23.759: E/Buffer Error(3717): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 18:48:23.759: E/JSON Parser(3717): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Just as a fyi: onPostExecute runs in the UI thread. There's no reason to make a runnable there.

Comment: @dymmeh: I am almost sure it would throw an exception in some cases if I remember correctly.

Comment: But I did not understand exactly what I should change. Can you give me an example so I can test?

And the strange thing is that it works correctly on emulators.

Comment: On which line does the code crash? Whats the output of `Log.d("Todas as rádios: ", json.toString());`? Do you have the correct permissions (seeing it works on through usb, and through emulator, adb manages a virtual connection, I suppose).

Comment: I edited the above with the output log

Comment: And because the difference when I install via usb end debug directly on the device? if the 2 are running on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: nsi.inf.br
```

Your device can't reach nsi.inf.br but the emulator, i.e. your workstation, can.

Check device's connectivity settings agains your workstation settings. Check if they are on same network and if there's proxy/firewall issues.

Comment: But this log where it appears, is precisely emulated. When I run on the device only those two log lines appear. And the network is the same, the same internet device. I used the wi-fi and tried to access the site directly nsi.inf.br the device browser, and accessed correctly.

Link to json is http://nsi.inf.br/nsistation/lista_radios.php

At least directly, the answer is correct.

Comment: The error `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of...` may occur if: (a) the JSON return is not what you expect or (b) the URL is returning a non JSON content (e.g. an http error page). I suggest printing the return as plain text and handle http error codes accordingly.

Comment: You were right. There was accessing the url, I changed:

This:

`private static String url_radios = "http://nsi.inf.br/nsistation/lista_radios.php";`

by:
`private static Uri url_radios = Uri.parse ("http://nsi.inf.br/nsistation/lista_radios.php");`

and it worked fine now.

Comment: @EdersondosSantos Can you please tell if you made any changes in the `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_radios, "GET", params);` statement